# react-bootstrap ButtonDropdown - can't set the width of the button itself to 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-bootstrap

I'm not sure if there's some quirk with react-bootstrap's DropdownButtons, but when I try to style the dropdown button like so:

```
<DropdownButton
    key={index}
    id="dropdown-basic-button"
    title={
        <div style={{
            maxWidth: '250px',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
        }}>
            {url}
        </div>
    }
    style={{margin: "auto", width: "100%", display: "block"}}
>
```

in order to try to get the button to fill its CSS grid cell completely, but it ends up looking something like this, clearly not filling its container:
[image]

I noticed in the chrome inspector, there are actual button components underneath this "DropdownButton" that, if I set the width of those to 100%, it achieves my goal. But, I don't know how to access these in code (see picture for reference).
[image]
You can see the div with my applied styles, but the <button type="button"...> component is what I really need to be editing. Is there a way to drill down into this and change its width?